# ec2launchv2 fails to get the primary IPv4 address

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2

I have created a Windows AMI with Packer and am using it to launch a large fleet of instances within EC2 using Terraform.

It is important for each instance to have a unique computer name. I would like these to be automatically assigned whenever a new machine is brought up (or, at least after the first reboot).

This is supposed to be a job for the EC2LaunchV2 program - it's supposed to rename the computer based on the hash of the internal IP, on every reboot.

And yet, somehow, when it is performing its tasks, it can't obtain the private IP, and thus fails to set the hostname properly. It also fails to add the private IP info to the desktop image.

An excerpt of `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2Launch\log\agent.log`:

```
2023-09-14 21:32:00 Info: Stage: postReadyUserData completed.
2023-09-14 21:32:00 Info: Run StartSsm task.
2023-09-14 21:32:00 Info: AmazonSSMAgent service already running.
2023-09-14 21:32:00 Info: AmazonSSMAgent is running now.
2023-09-14 21:32:00 Error: Error running task: failed to run task 'postReady-setHostName-0': Primary IP address not found.
2023-09-14 21:32:00 Info: Stage: postReady completed.
```

ipconfig seems to know the local IPv4 address just fine. How is this possible?